# Rewriting url (download.php/video.mp4 to download.php)

Tags: php, url-rewriting

How to rewrite URL so when my JW Player accesses a file through link (**http://www.example.com/download.php*/video.mp4***) it actually accesses **http://www.example.com/download.php**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule download\.php/(.*) /download.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need to configure on webserver level.

If you are on an Apache webserver, check out mod_rewrite. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html